# XMLParser in Pharo Claims U+00A0 is "Invalid UTF-8"

Tags: utf-8, smalltalk, pharo

Given the input:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<sms body=". what" />
```

Where the character after the "." in the body attribute of the sms tag is [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm);

I get the error:

> XMLEncodingException: Invalid UTF-8 character encoding (line 2) (column 13)

IIUC, the UTF-8 representation of that character is `0xC2 0xA0` [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Sure enough, bytes 72 and 73 of the input are 194 and 160 respectively.

This seems like a bug in XMLParser, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can't reproduce: `XMLDOMParser parse: '<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8'' standalone=''yes'' ?>
<sms body=".', #[194 160] asString, 'what" />'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Monty for coming to the rescue [on the Pharo User's list](http://forum.world.st/XMLParser-Claims-U-00A0-is-Invalid-UTF-8-tp4908525p4908548.html):

> You're double decoding. Use onFileNamed:/parseFileNamed: instead (and
>   the DOM printToFileNamed: family of messages when writing) and let
>   XMLParser take care this for you, or disable XMLParser decoding before
>   parsing with #decodesCharacters:.
>
> Longer explanation:
>
> The class #on:/#parse: take either a string or a stream (read the
>   definitions). You gave it a FileReference, but because the argument is
>   tested with isString and sent #readStream otherwise, it didn't blowup
>   then.
>
> File refs sent #readStream return file streams that do automatic
>   decoding. But XMLParser automatically attempts its own decoding too,
>   if:
>
> The input starts with a BOM or it can be inferred by null bytes
>   before or after the first non-null byte.
>
> There is an encoding declaration with a non-UTF-8 encoding.
>
> There is a UTF-8 encoding declaration but the stream is not a normal
>   ReadStream (your case).
>
> So it gets decoded twice, and the decoded value of the char causes the
>   error. I'll consider changing the heuristic to make less eager to
>   decode.